# Controlling a nested UITabController

Tags: swift, hierarchy, uitabcontroller

I have two `UITabController`s. One is controllable from `UIViewController`s that are nested within the scope of the first `UITabController` (lower in the hierarchy). When I change the `selectedIndex` of the one lower in the hierarchy it also change the other one. I've tried many things (see below) and nothing seems to work. Any idea how I can control one and not the other.

```
// Controls both
self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = curTab

// Doesn't do anything
(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTabBar") as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex = curTab

// Where stb is via classes to the storyboard of UITabController also doesn't work
stb.selectedIndex = curTab
```

Comment: I believe what you are suggesting breaks Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/) for Tab Bar Design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two UITabControllers. One is controllable from UIViewControllers that are nested within the scope of the first UITabController (lower in the hierarchy).

Containing a tab bar controller inside another tab bar controller [is not a supported configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html).

Comment: Oh thank you! Good to know, was losing my mind there... Will change how it works.